# How to have both a fixed navbar and fixed toolbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using a standard fixed navigation bar at the top of my site.  However, I also need to add a fixed toolbar, also at the top.  When I try to implement the toolbar as a second fixed navbar under the main navbar, the toolbar hides the main toolbar.

Can someone give me an example of doing this?

[Here is an example in Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9yPiTLYtcAzKKLkT1Ui7?p=info)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<!--This should not cover up the navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Toolbar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class toolbar to your second nav (the toolbar) like this:

( `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top toolbar">` )

Then add this to your CSS:

`.toolbar {
  margin-top: 51px;
}`

Also, when using fixed-top navbars, you need to add a padding-top to the content-pane or body to ensure they do not hide behind the navbar.
For 2 navbars both 51px high, add the following to your CSS:

`body {
  padding-top: 102px;
}`

You can adjust the value as per your convenience if you want to increase/decrease the padding. This value just accounts for the two fixed-top elements.

Comment: I added this to the plunkr to show the issue with this: the problem is that the content below the toolbar is then covered up.

Comment: That is not an issue with my proposed solution. That is a separate problem you have to solve with fixed-top navbars anyway. Editing my solution to account for this as well.